# Get the latest posts of the author in the loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to display the last 5 posts for current author in `single.php`.
These posts are registered in the table `wp_usermeta` as a `meta_key` (`user_posts`) and `meta_value` (`a:2:{i:0;s:4:"1336";i:1;s:4:"1334";}`) where 1336 and 1334 are post ids.

I've tried many methods to get more posts of current author, and found no solution.

```
<?php
 $post_ids = get_user_meta($user_id,'user_posts',true); 
 $posts = get_posts(array(
 'author' => get_the_author_id(), 
 'numberposts' => 5,  
 'orderby' => 'post_date', 
 'post__in' => explode(',', $post_ids)));
  if($posts) { echo '<ul>';
    foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark"  title="Permanent Link to <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?> </a></li>
    <?php }
    echo '</ul>';} ?>
```

Comment: please elaborate and show code.

Comment: Артем помоги пожалуйста с этим кодом :)

Comment: i wish could!! i definitely would help if i knew php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to fetch the latest 5 posts by current author in `single.php`

You dont need to parse that serialized string

```
$authorID = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 
     'author' => $authorID, 
     'numberposts' => 5,
     'orderby' => 'date'      
   ) 
 );
```

Check the two functions doc in wp codex [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [get_the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

You can then loop over the posts to get individual post details.

Comment: It not work properly. Each author has two types of posts, the second type is stored in wp_usermeta where meta_key  user_posts and meta_value  a: 2: {i: 0; s: 4: "1336"; i: 1; s: 4: "1334";}